# IIS: Redirect multiple URL's to same website

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm looking for the best way to redirect multiple URL's to one new URL. 
I have the following URLS:

- https://domain.app.company.com/application
- https://application.app.company.com

And I want those to redirect to: https://application.domain.app.company.com
What would be the best way to go about this (in IIS)?

I have tried using URL Rewriting, but I can only make that work for the first URL (https://domain.app.company.com/application):

```
<rule name="Application 1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*application" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://application.domain.app.company.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

For the second URL (https://application.app.company.com), I can make it work when setting up a new (empty) website in IIS (that listens to said URL) and add a httpRedirect in it.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://application.domain.app.company.com" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is this the recommended way to go about this? Or would there be another way?

Thank you

Schoof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind two url for the same IIS web site, I suggest you could try to below url rewrite. We could create two url rewrite rule to achieve your requirement.

```
<rule name="Application 1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*application" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://application.domain.app.company.com" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
                 <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="application.app.company.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://application.domain.app.company.com" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't seem to work now. When I go to https://application.app.company.com (HTTPS) I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Chrome. When I go to http://application.app.company.com (HTTP) I get the blue IIS screen. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that there are something wrong with your site bindings. I suggest you could check the application.app.company.com (HTTP)'s IIS site binding to make sure there is not other site binding to the 80 port. Besides, I think this is another issue, I suggest you could try to post the details information about your domain binding and site binding for your site now and start a new thread.